# How to change Facebook send dialog name and thumbnail?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

so I implemented Facebook send dialog in my Facebook app, but the problem is that it always displays server `name` and some random thumbnail. I put everything as it shown in Facebook documentation but nothing works.
This is my code:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: 'myName',
    picture: 'image/path',
    link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/APP_ID/',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog according to that page the parameters you can pass in are: app_id, redirect_uri, display, to, link. Neither name or picture are listed.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like Facebook doesn't support that anymore.